# Default acl not yielding the permissions i want in a shared directory

Tags: permissions, acl, umask

I am trying to share a directory between 2 users. Both users should **always** have rw permissions on all existing and newly created files and subdirectories under a given path.

I added both users to the same 2 groups (user www to group www and zip and user zip vice versa)

This is what I have done:

```
root@foo:/home/zip# mkdir -m 0775 testdir
root@foo:/home/zip# chown zip:zip testdir/
root@foo:/home/zip# chmod g+s testdir/
root@foo:/home/zip# ls -la
[...]
drwxrwsr-x  1 zip  zip             0 Jun 12 10:08 testdir

root@foo:/home/zip# getfacl testdir/
# file: testdir/
# owner: zip
# group: zip
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x

root@foo:/home/zip# setfacl -R -d -m \
u::rwX,g::rwX,u:zip:rwX,g:zip:rwX,u:www:rwX,g:www:rwX,o::r,mask:rw testdir/

root@foo:/home/zip# getfacl testdir/
# file: testdir/
# owner: zip
# group: zip
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www:rwx    #effective:rw-
default:user:zip:rwx    #effective:rw-
default:group::rwx      #effective:rw-
default:group:www:rwx   #effective:rw-
default:group:zip:rwx   #effective:rw-
default:mask::rw-
default:other::r--
```

But when I now upload a file via sftp (user zip) I do not get the desired result. The sftp process has a `umask` of `0002`. I checked `/proc/$pid/status` while uploading.

Case 1: Upload a file with permission 600

```
root@foo:/home/zip/testdir# getfacl test.jpg
# file: test.jpg
# owner: zip
# group: zip
user::rw-
user:www:rwx        #effective:---
user:zip:rwx        #effective:---
group::rwx          #effective:---
group:www:rwx       #effective:---
group:zip:rwx       #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
```

I do not understand why the mask is --- and the effective permissions are empty. **Shouldn't at least the named user permissions be effective?** What did I do wrong?

Case 2: Upload a file with `660`

```
root@foo:/home/zip/testdir# getfacl test2.jpg
# file: test2.jpg
# owner: zip
# group: zip
user::rw-
user:www:rwx        #effective:rw-
user:zip:rwx        #effective:rw-
group::rwx          #effective:rw-
group:www:rwx       #effective:rw-
group:zip:rwx       #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

So this seems to work OK.

This is a `btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=zlib:3,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/) volume (kernel 5.4.0)`.